# PDOException (1045) SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Laravel 4.2 MySQL 5.7

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mysql, php7

thanks for reading my question, I had been working on this error since a week reading questions in ServerFault, Stackoverflow and AskUbuntu but couldn't figure out the problem.

I have

- Lubuntu 16.04 (ubuntu distro)
- Nginx
- Laravel 4.2.17
- MySQL 5.7

I have a pre-existed project which I cloned from GitHub and everything is going well but when I go to a page which has to connect to database (Like attempt a login) I got this error:

*PDOException (1045) HELP*

*SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

[Graphic Description of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNy6i.png)

### FILES INVOLVE

I have a .env file in the project and I had named it **.env.local.php** this is the file:

```
<?php
/**
* Variables de entorno .env.php
* Si se requiere cargar otros valores para un entorno diferente al de produccion (local, development, etc.)
* cree un archivo con el nombre asi:
*  - local => .env.local.php
*  - development => .env.development.php
*/
return [

'DATABASE_NAME' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
'DATABASE_USER' => 'DATABASE_USER',
'DATABASE_PASSWORD' => 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',

/*
 * social
 * '$RED$_IDENTIFIER'   => '',
 * '$RED$_SECRET'       => '',
 * '$RED$_CALLBACK_URI' => '',
 */

'GOOGLE_IDENTIFIER'     => 'GOOGLE_IDENTIFIER',
'GOOGLE_SECRET'         => 'GOOGLE_SECRET',
'GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI'   => 'GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI',

'FACEBOOK_IDENTIFIER'   => 'FACEBOOK_IDENTIFIER',
'FACEBOOK_SECRET'       => 'FACEBOOK_SECRET',
'FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URI' => 'FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URI',

/**
 * PayU configs
 * PAYU_TEST: 1 = Modo prueba, 0 = Modo Produccion
 */
'PAYU_MACRO_ACCOUNT_ID' => 654321,
'PAYU_MICRO_ACCOUNT_ID' => 123456,
'PAYU_MERCHANT_ID' => 123456,
'PAYU_API_KEY' => 'ABCabc123DEFdef456GHIghi78',
'PAYU_API_LOGIN' => '123abc456def789',
'PAYU_TEST' => 1,

];
```

---

I have a **database.php** file in /var/www/kinbuweb/app/config/local/database.php I highlight the /config/local path which I've been reading is the configuration if I have a local enviroment (and I had named my file .env.**local**.php) the file in the path:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'homestead',
        'username' => 'homestead',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'  => 'pgsql',
        'host'    => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'homestead',
        'username' => 'homestead',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix'  => '',
        'schema'  => 'public',
    ],

],

];
```

---

On the other hand I have a file out of the local folder (Path: /var/www/kinbuweb/app/config) which is called **database.php** too, I think is the general configuration it has:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch'       => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default'     => 'mysql',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__ . '/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql'  => [
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => $_ENV['DATABASE_NAME'],
        'username' => $_ENV['DATABASE_USER'],
        'password' => $_ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'pgsql'  => [
        'driver'  => 'pgsql',
        'host'    => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'forge',
        'username' => 'forge',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix'  => '',
        'schema'  => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'   => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations'  => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis'       => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

### What I had tried

1. Use the credentials in the local (/var/www/kinbuweb/app/config/local/database.php) **database.php** configuration like this:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
   * Variables de entorno .env.php
   * Si se requiere cargar otros valores para un entorno diferente al de produccion (local, development, etc.)
   * cree un archivo con el nombre asi:
   *  - local => .env.local.php
   *  - development => .env.development.php
   */
   return [

   'DATABASE_NAME' => 'homestead',
   'DATABASE_USER' => 'homestead',
   'DATABASE_PASSWORD' => 'secret',



   'GOOGLE_IDENTIFIER'     => 'GOOGLE_IDENTIFIER',
   'GOOGLE_SECRET'         => 'GOOGLE_SECRET',
   'GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI'   => 'GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI',

   'FACEBOOK_IDENTIFIER'   => 'FACEBOOK_IDENTIFIER',
   'FACEBOOK_SECRET'       => 'FACEBOOK_SECRET',
   'FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URI' => 'FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URI',


   'PAYU_MACRO_ACCOUNT_ID' => 654321,
   'PAYU_MICRO_ACCOUNT_ID' => 123456,
   'PAYU_MERCHANT_ID' => 123456,
   'PAYU_API_KEY' => 'ABCabc123DEFdef456GHIghi78',
   'PAYU_API_LOGIN' => '123abc456def789',
   'PAYU_TEST' => 1,

   ];
   ```
2. Aggregate the port to the database configuration in the local folder like this:

   ```
   <?php

   return [

   'connections' => [

   'mysql' => [
       'driver'   => 'mysql',
       'host'     => 'localhost:3306',
       'database' => 'homestead',
       'username' => 'homestead',
       'password' => 'secret',
       'charset'  => 'utf8',
       'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
       'prefix'   => '',
       ],

   'pgsql' => [
       'driver'  => 'pgsql',
       'host'    => 'localhost',
       'database' => 'homestead',
       'username' => 'homestead',
       'password' => 'secret',
       'charset' => 'utf8',
       'prefix'  => '',
       'schema'  => 'public',
      ],

   ],

   ];
   ```

And while I got the same error: 
*PDOException (1045) HELP*

*SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

Any ideas with I could solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do add privilege for your user 'homestead' in your mysql for you database.

Log into  mysql and add privilege like this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your password of MySQL

```
mysql > grant all privileges on homestead *.* to 'homestead'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

'password' here is in your database.php

If you are in local enviroment the path for database.php is:

> yourporjectfolder/app/config/local

```
mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Hello @romain  I'll try. In 'password' which password I had to place, from the MySQL or from one in database? Thanks for answering

Comment: The password of your database, not your root password. The command grant all privileges will create an user 'homestead' with password 'password' who will have all privileges on your database 'homestead'. After you will can update your database configuration in your file in the local folder with this user access ('database' => 'homestead',
    'username' => 'homestead',
    'password' => 'password')

Comment: Solved (edited answer). Now the error is SQL [1049] Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046303/cant-connect-to-mysql-error-1049?noredirect=1#comment71266842_42046303